# Add custom code snippet to visual studio intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-snippets

There is [this nice program](http://snippetdesigner.codeplex.com/) that enable you to easily create code snippets. I already managed to create snippets but it will be nice if the snippet where to show up in visual studio's intellisense.

For example visual studio already has several built in code snippets such as the one for creating the constructor of a class:

[image]

note that it was really easy and fast to use it.

On the other hand when I create my custom snippet with the program that I provided on the first link, these are the steps that I have to do in order to use it:

[image]

on step 3 I have to select the folder where the snippet that I created is located then on step 4 locate it.

It will be nice if I could use the code snippet that I created just like the ones that visual studio provides like the constructor one that I showed on the first image. Maybe if I place the snippet that I just created and place it where visual studio store the built in onces it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add [a shortcut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5dewx15.aspx) to the snippet.

after adding the shortcut it appears on the intellisense without having to navigate to the folder where it was located by pressing ctrl+k and ctrl+x